# Google Play App Questions

Tags: android, google-play, publish

1) Does google put limit number of downloads for every app ?
if no, Will it be more money paid for more downloads?
Example :
1000 Downloads --> 1$ here no Taxes from google
1000000 Downloads --> 1000$
- Is there any taxes from google 2% for example? 
1000000000 Downloads --> 1000000$  - Is there any taxes from google 10% for example?

2) How much is it paid to register for google play account and Will I pay for every year the same price?

3) Does it differ from a person who will buy an account to a company?
if yes, Does it differ from company members?

4) Must I put advertisements over my app ? if I refused Will I pay for refusing ?

5) How much can I gain from advertisements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1-Does google put limit number of downloads for every app ? if no, Will it be more money paid for more downloads? example : 1000 Downloads --> 1$ here no Taxes from google 1000000 Downloads --> 1000$ - Is there any taxes from google 2% for example? 1000000000 Downloads --> 1000000$ - Is there any taxes from google 10% for example?

**NO, there is no limit on downloads.**

> 2-How much is it paid to register for google play account and Will I pay for every year the same price?

**It's $25 for a lifetime access.**

> 3-Does it differ from a person who will buy an account to a company? if yes, Does it differ from company members?

**There are seprate options for individual accounts and company accounts**

> 4-Must I put advertisements over my app ? if I refused Will I pay for refusing ?

**Putting Ads are optional, if you want to generate extra income using ads, then only you need to add advts. It's completely your choice.**

> 5- How much can I gain from advertisements ?

**The Rate/Price varies from different locations. and [AdMob](https://www.google.co.in/admob/) decides the prices.**

For More information about Google Play developer account please visit [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer#topic=3450769)